# Is the HSP with the symmetric group exactly equivalent to the Graph Isomorphism problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing, group-theory

It is well known that an algorithm to solve the Hidden Subgroup Problem (HSP) with the symmetric group can solve the Graph isomorphism problem.

But is this true in reverse? Will an algorithm for graph isomorphism be useful in solving the HSP with the symmetric group?

The HSP is only really useful for connecting applicable problems, but I am asking this for theory.